# ItemCLick in Android MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I have defined my view Layout as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <Mvx.MvxListView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          local:MvxBind="ItemClick PopulateMetricsCat2Command ; ItemsSource RatingList"
          local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_met2" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**and List ItemTemplate is as follows**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#ffffff">
     <TextView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           local:MvxBind="Text MetricName" />
     <RatingBar
           android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:numStars="5"
           android:stepSize="1"
           local:MvxBind="Rating ResponseValue" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

I have binded a command on **ItemClick** event in My MvxListView, but whenever I select some item from List,**a specified command is not get executed**.Control is nat get trasferred to a command.

That command is as follows

```
    private void DoGoPopulateMetrics(UserRating r)
    {
        ShowViewModel<PopulateMetricsByCat2ViewModel>(r);
    }
```

Why it not calling this command?

```
    private Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand<StarRating>   
                                                     _ratingSelectedCommand;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get{
            _ratingSelectedCommand = _ratingSelectedCommand ?? new 
             Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand<StarRating>(DoSelectItem);
            return _ratingSelectedCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DoSelectItem(StarRating r)
    {
        ShowViewModel<PopulateMetricsByCat2ViewModel>(r);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing PopulateMetricsCat2Command

```
public ICommand PopulateMetricsCat2Command 
{
   get { return new MvxCommand(DoGoPopulateMetrics); }
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do seems correct but I can't help any further without seeing code.

Comment: ok,I am editing my post and inserting my code in it,please check it out.

Comment: I don't see any changes in the original post.

Comment: I renamed PopulateMetricsCat2Command to ItemSelectedCommand and my code of this command is posted in original post.